# Fuzzy search to file and paste in path at cursor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to be able to

1. Place my cursor
2. fuzzy search and select a file *at the cursor*
3. the relative path of the selected file is inserted at the cursor

Is this possible with VSCode?

**SOLUTION**: found [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=capaj.vscode-exports-autocomplete), even better!

Comment: That is two questions in one, no? Fuzzy Search and then pasting at cursor?

Comment: Updated for clarity